# List with hidden "prepended" li elements

Tags: html, css

am trying to make list ("ul"), where later then i add  values with jquery, with **.prepend()** function. I would like to make all these new  values, to be hidden, like out  of  div and later i will show them but then i add them, they must be hidden. Are  there  any way to do something like that?
[image]

I made a picture to show my problem, so what i wanted to do, id like i add  5 and 6 li element with JQuery and they must be in that "hidden area", and list in "visible area" wont change. So far i made that list, but then i add new element  it goes in visible area, and li elements  order on visible area goes like:"6, 5, 1, 2".

EDIT.

I tired to solve my problem with [**@mboldt**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25620861/1406714) suggestion, but it didnt worked for me or i did something incorrectly. My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .item-list-inner {
    float:left; 
    width: 600px; 
    overflow: hidden;  

    border:2px solid black;
    }

    .item-list-ul {
        position:relative;
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width:9999px;       
        height:100px;
    } 

    .item-list-ul li {
        display: inline-block;
       *display: inline;   /*IE7*/
       *zoom: 1;           /*IE7*/
        float: left;
    }

    .item{
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:7px;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
    <div class="item-list-inner">
        <ul class="item-list-ul">
                <li>
                    <div class="item">1</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">2</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">3</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">4</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">5</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">6</div>
                </li>
        </ul>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i tried  to prepend new  element  with jquery:

```
$(".item-list-ul").prepend("<li><div class='item'>jquery</div></li>")
```

New li element  goes in from of list, instead in that "hidden" place:
First row is the result i want to get, like new  element  goes in that invisible (hidden area) and wont  be shown until i rotate list.
Second row is the  result i got now  with my code. As  you see then i prepend new  li element it goes in front of list but in visible area, and moves other li elements.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far? An online demo would be great also.

Comment: What do you mean by hidden area?? `display: none` ??? or out of the view `left: -1000px` ????

Comment: In that case, once you add a new item to the list you also move the whole list 80px (the width of one list item) to the left to make sure the prepended item moves into the invisible area.

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them class ".addClass( 'hidden' )" and in css file ".hidden{display:none;}

Later you just need to ".removeClass( 'hidden' )" to show them.

Comment: Does it order the elements on visible area as `6, 5, 1, 2`? I don't think so. IMO this question is too broad.

Comment: He want that those new elements would be on top of list

Answer (score 1):

If you create the list item before you add it to the list you can sipmly hide it via the jQuery method like this

```
var item = $("<li>hidden item</li>");
$(item).hide();
$("#list").prepend(item);
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gof8t2Lu/), it only shows 3 list items but if you look at the source code with firebug you'll see another hidden list item was added.

However if you are trying to implement something like a slider, the the overflow-property might be the thing you are looking for (hard to tell with the information given).

**EDIT**
Now that you updated your question and I think I now know what you are trying to do I created a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23st3h6v/5/) with another solution. Check it out and see if that is what you are trying to do and if the code helps you.
In the jsfiddle there are two buttons, one to scrolle the list to the right and one to prepend an item to the "invisible area" on the left of the list. 
Note: This is not really clean, i.e. when scrolling there are still borders showing, which should actually be hidden but I think this is good enough to show the idea.

Comment: Pretty much i am aiming to make  something like slider, like elements goes like form right  to left, and  after elements reach hidden area on left side, it s removed from list( it is not like  carousel there they go round and round)

Comment: I did something similar once and your visible area (between the red lines) would be a div with a fixed width and overflow: hidden. The ul-element should be positioned relative and you can move it to the left or right via javascript to slide list items in or out of the visible area.

Comment: I tried to do something like you suggested but so far it goes wrong way for me. Edited first post with results.